# Magento new products widget blurry

Tags: magento, widget, block, magento-1.9, blurry

The small images of Magento's (1.9.0.1.) built in new products widget are blurry. I am using the default rwd theme and it does not seem to happen to other widgets such as recently viewed products.
It also displays on multiple rows instead of alongside each other.

Sorry I can't post pictures yet
Thanks!

Comment: I noticed it takes the 85px version of the image instead of the 210px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright I found a solution:
I had to modify a line in new_grid.phtml in **app/design/frontend/[rwd]/default/template/catalog/product/widget/new/content**

Change the 85 to 210 in this line:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
```

Comment: I'm running Magento ver. 1.9.2.0, and this change does not fix my problem (it appears to be the new default).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
The image resizing is the 'new.phtml' file, but the theme RWD does not have this file.

Copy the file **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml**
to **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/** and change the size in line 35.

Old:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135) ?>" width="135" height="135"
```

New:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(272) ?>" width="272" height="272"
```

I changed to 272 to not get blurred.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on magento 1.9.2:

Edit this file (if there isn´t this file, copy from base/default theme):
**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml**

And then replace the < a > tag with this code at line 35:

```
<?php $_imgSize=300; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize) ?>" width="<?php echo $_imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $_imgSize ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
```